# What is the simplest C# function to parse a JSON string into an object?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, json

What is the simplest C# function to parse a JSON string into a object and display it (C# XAML WPF)? (for example object with 2 arrays -  arrA and arrB)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YourObjectType));

YourObjectType yourObject = (YourObjectType)serializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
```

You could also use the `JavaScriptSerializer`, but `DataContractJsonSerializer` is supposedly better able to handle complex types.

Oddly enough JavaScriptSerializer was once deprecated (in 3.5) and then resurrected because of ASP.NET MVC (in 3.5 SP1). That would definitely be enough to shake my confidence and lead me to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` since it is hard baked for WCF.

Comment: I'd use this over serializers built earlier in the framework's lifespan.

Comment: You HAVE to add a refernce to this first then `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;`

Answer (score 65):

Just use the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/37810) library. It lets you parse Json format strings very easily:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"
{
    ""something"":""value"",
    ""jagged"":
    {
        ""someother"":""value2""
    }
}");

string something = (string)o["something"];
```

Documentation: **[Parsing JSON Object using JObject.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)**

Comment: Json.NET is a professional library tested and proved to be very much more flexible and efficient. Highly recommended.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only option that allows for generic object type parsing, the other answers are bound to a certain object type.

Comment: Great solution. Although for me worked like this `JToken something = o["something"];`

Comment: Sometimes it seems silly to pull in an external library if you need to parse json for one thing. Using DataContractJsonSerializer is a much more practical approach here. It's like pulling in EntityFramework because your application does literally a few database queries.

Comment: Using `System.Text.Json`, we can do `JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonString);`

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you want:

```
JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
T obj = JSS.Deserialize<T>(String);
```

Comment: I needed to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` to see this

Comment: T needs to be a specific type, does it not? I can't just parse a random JSON string.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a structure that represents JSON keys (in case if you exactly know it) and then you can easily deserialize JSON string into your structure. In my examle I've deserialized a response from Google Cloud Message server:

```
class templateResponse
{
    public String multicast_id;
    public String success;
    public String failure;
    public String canonical_ids;
    public Result[] results;

    public class Result
    {
        public String message_id;
        public String registration_id;
        public String error;
    };
}
```

incoming JSON was:

```
"\"multicast_id\":7400896764380883211,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1351777805148960%39895cf0f9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

So, use

```
templateResponse result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<templateResponse>(json);
```

and you will get deserialized `result` object

Comment: The example JSON and associated class was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would echo the Json.NET library, which can transform the JSON response into a XML document. With the XML document, you can easily query with XPath and extract the data you need. I find this pretty useful.