# Passing JSON object to MVC Controller

Tags: json

I can successfully make a jQuery Ajax call into my C# Controller and receive back an XML string, but I need to in turn gather some Portfolio dates and package them up into a JSON object so I can send them back into another C# Controller.
If it's a C# issue, then I apologize if I'm in the wrong forum...however I'd like to pass my JSON object into the server side controller ..

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
        var nodeDatesJson = {"nodedates":        // CREATE JSON OBJECT OF DATE STRINGS
                            { "date": 01/20/2012,
                              "date": "01/21/2012" } };
        getTradeContribs(thisPfId, nodeDatesJson.nodedates.date);
```

Now call the next js function:

```
 function getTradeContribs(pfid, nodedates) {
        //alert(nodedates);
        $.ajax({                                // GET TRADE CONTRIBS FROM SERVER !!
            url: "/Portfolios/getTradeContribs?portfolioId=" + pfid + "&nodedates=" + nodedates,
            type: "GET",    // or "PUT"
            dataType: "json",               
            async: true,
            success: parseTradeContribs,
            error: function (error) {
                alert("failed in opening Trade Contribs file !!!");
            }
        });
    }
    function parseTradeContribs(data) {
        alert("In parseTradeContribs..." );
        $(data).find("Trade").each(function(){
            $(".TradeContrib").append($(this).text());
        })
    }
```

and my C# controller is trying to **read in the "nodedates" JSON object**, but **HOW** do I read it in ?

```
   public string getTradeContribs(string portfolioId, **string nodedates**)
        {

            // Build Portfolio Select request here !
            RequestBuilder rzrRequest = new RequestBuilder();

            // REQUEST FOR CONTRIBUTIONS !
            // ... more code here..
            xmlResponse.LoadXml(contribResponse);

            string jsonTest = @" {""nodedates"": ""date"":""01/01/2012""}";

            //return xmlResponse.OuterXml;  // WORKS FINE
            return "<Trade><TradeId>1234</TradeId></Trade>";    // RETURN TEST XML STR

        }
```

thank you in advance...
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to receive a list of dates in a MVC action is to bind to a collection. What this means is that you should put your dates and other attributes in a form with the following naming convention:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dates" value="2012-1-20" />  
<input type="hidden" name="dates" value="2012-1-21" />
```

Then you should serialize this form (look into jquery's docs for this) and post its data to your action, which will be something along the lines of:

```
public ActionResult getTradeContribs(string portfolioId, IList<DateTime> dates) {
  // Do your work here
}
```

You should really take a look into MVC Model binding and collection binding as well:
[Model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
[Model binding objects](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-work-with-model-binders-in-an-mvc-application)

---

Also, if I may, your javascript object has two properties with the same name, which is probably not what you mean. If you want to have multiple dates stored somewhere in a object, you should use an array:

```
    var nodeDatesJson = {"nodedates":  
                        [ "01/20/2012", "01/21/2012" ] };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I didn't understand your doubt very well...but here it goes:

Maybe you should pass the json, well-formatted, as a string and use some C# parser.

This way you can get a object in server-side as same as the Json object in javascript.

=]

Comment: the server side is exactly the problem. I'm trying to figure out how to read in the json object in my c# code...i.e.  public string getTradeContribs(string portfolioId, dynamic nodedates)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C#...But doesn't C# have some function to parse a string into a Json object?? Or doesn't have a function to parse a string into a C# object?? Like Java has Jackson, Gson libraries that do that... =/

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object) helps how to convert a string to a c# object...

Comment: There's another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-simpliest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-json-string-into-object) here...

Comment: Look at @MarceloZabani answer below...it seems being correct..Gained my upvote =]

Comment: Thanks Victor. His array idea worked out better. I'm now trying to parse out the "nodedates" in C# as follows...

Comment: var nodes = ser.Deserialize<dynamic>(nodedates);
            foreach (var date in nodes)
            {
                string theKey = date.Key;
                string thisNode = date.Value[0];
            }

Comment: but I'd like to use a clean iDictionary type...however not sure how to implement...

Comment: I'll contact Marcelo again...he can help you better than me...hauhuahhua