# How to pass a jsonObject and a json array as ajaxdata to Asp.net

Tags: jquery, json, webforms

lets say i a json object and a json array. i need it to pass those as ajaxdata to asp.net.

Below is myCode Code

```
function insertNewBookingInfo(jsonstaticobj1232, jsonarray646) {
      try {
          debugger;
         //jsonstaticobj1232 is a json object
         //jsonarray646 is a json array
          var dataAjax = { "jsonstaticobj1232": jsonstaticobj1232, "jsonarray646": jsonarray646 };

          console.log(JSON.stringify(dataAjax));
          jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'WalkReserve.aspx/insertNewBookingInfo',
              type: "POST",
              data: JSON.stringify(dataAjax),
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(data.d);
              },
              error: function (result) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log('Failed' + result.responseText);
              }

          });
      } catch (e) {
          debugger;
          console.log(e.message);
          alert(e.message);
      }

  }
```

Server Code

```
 [WebMethod]
            public static string insertNewBookingInfo(string jsonstaticobj1232, string jsonarray646) //, string jsonarray646
            {

       // BAL.insertNewBookingInfo(jsonstaticobj1232, jsonstaticobj1232); //, jsonarray646
        return "ABC";
    }
```

**[For Bigger Picture click here](http://s17.postimg.org/4mhtcgmsf/Untitled_1_51_2_11_2014.png)**

now im getting this error

what is the problem. am i missing something??

Comment: You have one problem to begin with: your JSON is not valid. Strings in JSON are in double quotes.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. i have fixed it but now getting another error. i have posted the new problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of am1r_5h. i found that changing incoming datatype to dynamic solved my problem

```
public static string insertNewBookingInfo(dynamic jsonstaticobj1232, dynamic jsonarray646) 
        {

            // BAL.insertNewBookingInfo(jsonstaticobj1232, jsonstaticobj1232); //, jsonarray646
            return "ABC2";
        }
```

Solved My Problem.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you `stringify` your data in client, and deserializing at `server`?

in client:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataAjax)
```

and in server:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer o = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
o.Deserialize<MyClass>(stringified_dataAjax);
//OR
o.ConvertToType<MyClass>(stringified_dataAjax);
```

and `MyClass` type is :

```
public class MyClass
    {
        // you need to change 'int' type to type which exactly they are
        public int jsonstaticobj1232 { get; set; } // int => your 'reservation' object type probably
        public int jsonarray646 { get; set; } // int => List<T> : T is your corresponding object
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain  what is have to do in server apart from creating class. lets say "insertNewBookingInfo" is function name in the server

Comment: for too long character in my comment, i must post it as answer, see answer

Answer (score 0):

in server, your data you passed is `string` `(JSON format)` and you need to convert this, to specific class to access your property you want typesafe, if you have a object in javascript like this

```
{name: "mark", age: 35}
```

when you stringify your object that be changed to

```
"{"name":"mark","age":35}"
```

and when you passed this to server, you need to convert this string to a class, to access properties you want, and for this purpose, you need to a server side class, which its properties conform to name and type of your javascript object properties, something like this

```
class anyClasName // it doesn't matter
    {
        public string name { get; set; } // the name of property must be exactly same as your javascript object property
        public byte age { get; set; }    // and the type of property should be something which property of javascript object can be convert to
    }
```

form more help follow: [Deserialize-JSON-with-Csharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-Csharp.aspx) and [json-string-to-c-sharp-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358374/json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Comment: changing string to dynamic solved my problem. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

and also i have posted here a answer to using `WebMethod` i think be useful to you,
[WebMethod to async ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696087/ajax-submitting-in-asp-net/21697330#21697330)