# Ajax submitting in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am very new to asp.net web development.
I have a form like this

```
<form id="frmNewUser">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User ID
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text1" name="txtUserId" type="text" class="easyui-validatebox" data-options="required:true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtUsername" type="text" class="easyui-validatebox" data-options="required:true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The idea is to add a new user and I need to do it asynchronously. So I added One method behind aspx page as

```
[WebMethod]
 public static void AddUser()
 {

 }
```

And I have written ajax form submitting as

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "UserManagment.aspx/AddUser",
           data: $("#frmNewUser").serialize(),
           success: function (msg) {
             alert("hello");
           },
           error: function (xhr, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                    alert("Error" + xhr.status);
           }

       });
```

My doubts are
1. How to deserialize the form data in `AddUser()` method and what should be the parameters
2. The method `AddUser()` is never getting hit after ajax submitting .After debugging I come to know that only `Page_Load()` is getting Invoked. How could I get the control upto `AddUser()`. I already have added

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I Sorted it out
Followed as per http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_post_data_to_pagemethod.ashx

Basically page methods are expecting data in JSON format. So I modified  ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserManagment.aspx/AddUser",
                dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
                timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout  
                data: JSON.stringify({ formVars : $("#frmNewUser").serializeArray() }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("hello");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                    alert("Error" + xhr.status);
                }  


            });
```

The "code behind" contains following code

```
public static void AddUser(NameValue[] formVars)
        {
           //formvars will contain list of values
            foreach (NameValue nv in formVars)
            {
                // strip out ASP.NET form vars like _ViewState/_EventValidation  
                if (!nv.name.StartsWith("__"))
                {
                   string ss = nv.value; 

                }
            }  
            return;
        }



        public class NameValue
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

to use `WebMethod`, you can do this... and there is no need to any `httpmodule`

server side (on a aspx page, it doesn't work on `User Controls (.ascx)`):

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void addUser(string Params)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var oParamter =  serializer.Deserialize<Paramter>(Params);
    }

    private class Paramter
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

html markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User ID
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text1" name="txtUserId" type="text" class="easyui-validatebox" data-options="required:true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text2" name="txtUsername" type="text" class="easyui-validatebox" data-options="required:true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>

                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="submit" onclick="Button1_click()" />

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

client javascript:

```
<script>

    function param() {

        this.id = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
        this.name = document.getElementById("Text2").value;
    };

    function Button1_click() {

        PageMethods.addUser(JSON.stringify(new param()), successHandler, failedHandler);
    };

    function successHandler() {
        alert("operation done successfully");
    };

    function failedHandler() {
        alert("operation failed");
    };

</script>
```