# LINQ or REGEX to extract certain text from a string

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a string in my C# model populated with this string:

"[{\"ta_id\":97497,\"partner_id\":\"229547\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547\"},{\"ta_id\":97832,\"partner_id\":\"id34234\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234\"}]"

Is there a way, using LINQ or RegEx, that I could parse out the partner_id's - so I ended up with a list object with:

```
229547
id34234
```

Thanks for your help, Mark

Comment: That looks like a JSON string, so you could parse it to a class using [Json Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.110).aspx). [This might help too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-the-simplest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: You can also take a look at this popular JSON serializer: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: @musefan indeed, and heres a nice example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi - what class does DataContractJsonSerializer belong in?  I'm using Visual Studio, and the usual Ctl + . isn't giving any options.  I have installed Newtonsoft.Json from nuget.  Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used any JSON parser but if it comes to Regex you could try something like this:

```
private static void regexString()
{
    string myString = "[{\"ta_id\":97497,\"partner_id\":\"229547\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547\"},{\"ta_id\":97832,\"partner_id\":\"id34234\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234\"}]";

    string[] stringList = Regex.Split(myString, "},{");

    for (int i=0; i<stringList.Length ;i++)
    {
        stringList[i] = Regex.Split(Regex.Split(stringList[i], "partner_id\\\":\\\"")[1], "\\\",\\\"partner_url\\\"")[0];
    }
}
```

Also there is a nice website to help you with creating your own regex patterns in the future, check it out:

[gskinner.com](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

And a nice and short tutorial:

[www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your link having partner id always-

```
   string Name = "[{\"ta_id\":97497,\"partner_id\":\"229547\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547\"},{\"ta_id\":97832,\"partner_id\":\"id34234\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234\"}]";

        string[] splittedString = Regex.Split(Name, "}");
        List<string> allIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in splittedString)
        { 
            var ids =Regex.Split(i, "/");
            string id = ids[ids.Length - 1];
            allIds.Add(id);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the general format of the string then this regex should work

```
(?i)(?<=(partner_id).{5})\w+
```

Test [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

This from your string will get

```
229547 and id34234
```

`(?i)` = Case insesitivity

`(?<=(partner_id).{5})` = postive *lookbehind* for parter_id then any 5 characters which in this case will be `\":\"`

`\w+` = Any alphanumeric characters one or more times

Hope this helped

Comment: @ +1 for optimalization ,time for me to learn `lookbehind` more... Anyway could you explain (?i) for me as I don't really get it.

Comment: Your `{5}` should be `{3}`.

Comment: Yeah sure (?i) basically if you have say the string 'tafari', to match this you might use [a-z]+ but this only matches lower case 'tafari' what if you were to have 'TafARI' in some cases or 'TAFAri' etc. Yes you could use [a-zA-Z]+ but my preffered way is to use (?i) which will match stings matched by your regex but they can be upper or lower case or a mixture of both. So to match any cased 'Tafari' i would use (?i)[a-z]+. Does this help?

Comment: @Srb1313711 so basically it would be the same as **(\w?)** ?

Comment: Yes and no \w will get both upper and lower case but will also get numbers, if your just searching for strings I would advise using [a-z] to avoid matching anything unwanted. The same with numbers I would use [0-9] instead of \d as \d matches all Unicode characters not just 0-9. Also by specifying (?i) at the beginning you don't have to keep repeating [a-zA-Z] unless you only want case insensitivity in certain places.

Comment: @Srb1313711 well obviously I understand it better now, so thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

Since this is JSON, you probably shouldn't bother trying to get a regex working. Instead, you can parse the JSON and then use LINQ.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

...

string s = "[{\"ta_id\":97497,\"partner_id\":\"229547\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547\"},{\"ta_id\":97832,\"partner_id\":\"id34234\",\"partner_url\":\"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234\"}]";
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object[] objects = (object[])j.DeserializeObject(s);
string[] ids = objects.Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
                      .Select(dict => (string)dict["partner_id"])
                      .ToArray();
```

It's a little messy to deserialize it to an object, because you don't have any type information. If you're not afraid of making a small class to deserialize into, you can do something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public string partner_id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

...

JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string[] ids = j.Deserialize<Foo[]>(s).Select(x => x.partner_id).ToArray();
```

Note that there are other options for deserializing JSON. I simply chose the most general-purpose one that's built in.