# C# strip away xml from a string

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

My xamarin mobile app consumes soap service, when i make a login request the response returned has both Json and xml. I am interested only in the json string. Can any one tell me the way to parse the following response.

`[{"Result":"true","HasError":false,"UserMsg":null,"ErrorMsg":null,"TransporterID":"327f6da2-d797-e311-8a6f-005056a34fa8"}]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

`String.IndexOf` will give you the index of the xml part, then you can use `String.Substring`:

```
string str = @"[{ ""Result"":""true"",""HasError"":false,""UserMsg"":null,""ErrorMsg"":null,""TransporterID"":""327f6da2-d797-e311-8a6f-005056a34fa8""}]
<? xml version = ""1.0"" encoding = ""utf-8"" ?>< soap : Envelope xmlns: soap = ""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns: xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns: xsd = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" >< soap:Body >< LoginResponse xmlns = ""http://tempuri.org/"" /></ soap:Body ></ soap:Envelope >";

string json = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("<? xml")); 

Console.WriteLine(json); // [{ "Result":"true","HasError":false,"UserMsg":D":"327f6da2-d797-e311-8a6f-005056a34fa8"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Substring` method as follows:

```
string response = "<<The response you got>>";
string jsonResponse = response.Substring(0, response.IndexOf("<?"));
```

The `0` is the starting index (when to start extracting the substring) and the `IndexOf` will return the index of `<?` which is the start of the XML part of the response. You can read about the `Substring` Method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Therefore, you have filtered the JSON response from the whole string. (For a how-to parse JSON data, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-the-simplest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object)).