# MVC convert json stored as a string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a model object

```
model.ToDoList =  { "completed": false, "taskId": "in01", "memberName": "JD", "dueDate": "Mon Apr 25 16:09:18 EDT 2016" }, { "completed": false, "taskId": "in02", "memberName": "JD", "dueDate": "Mon Apr 25 16:09:18 EDT 2016" }, { "completed": false, "taskId": "in16", "memberName": "JD", "dueDate": "Wed Apr 20 16:09:18 EDT 2016" } ]
```

This is a json object stored as a string. How can I convert the string into an object in the view? I am trying to loop through that ojbect and display on the screen

```
@model Gallant.Models.Enrollment

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Completed</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Member</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Upload Document</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ToDoList)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally "parse JSON" would be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-the-simplest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object, but what you are asking is so strange... so probably you need some other answer.

Comment: Try to deserialize into dictionary<string,string> and then iterate it. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to display json is like below:

In your view, just use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize json and iterate it.

```
@{
    var json= "{ 'completed': false, 'taskId': 'in01'}" ;
    Dictionary<string, string> jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    foreach(var item in jsonObject){
        <div>
            <label>@item.Key : </label>
            <span>@item.Value</span>
        </div>

    }
 }
```

Comment: This is what i am looking to do. Except i want var json = model.ToDoList

Comment: var json = model.ToDoList;
    List<ToDoTask> jsonObject =      Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoTask>>(json);
        foreach (var item in jsonObject)
    {
        <div>
            <spanl>@item.dueDate </span>
            <span>@item.taskId</span>
        </div>

    }

Comment: If this answer helped you, please do up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.NET to deserialize this to either a class instance or an anonymous object. Here's how you would do it for an anonymous type, defining the properties you want deserialized:

```c#
var result = new[]{ new { Completed = false, TaskId = "", MemberName = "", DueDate = "" } };
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(model.TodoList, result);
```

Or to your own custom class:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(model.TodoList);
```

Seems like it would be better suited to do this parsing outside of the view though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read about NewtonJson and download it from her http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

Secondly, you should create a class with all fields that you have in JSON. Like this

```
public class ListItem
{
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string TaskId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Enrolment class you should do something like this

```
public class Enrolment
{
     public IEnumerable<ListItem> ToDoList{ get; private set; }

     public void ApplyJSON(string json)
     {
          //Magic :)
          YourList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ListItem>>(json);
     }
}
```

Finally, replace your line

```
model.ToDoList =  { "completed": false, "taskId": "in01",...}
```

with model.ApplyJson("{ "completed": false, "taskId": "in01",...}")

Thus, in the @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ToDoList) you'll have list of ListItem items and you can do everything you want.