# Using c#, ios to get a JSON address from an API

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin

I am trying to make for example a simple weather app. Mine is for an Air Quality API.

I had this code but I didn't think it would work with JSON.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
...
var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text and store in this variable
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string localFilename = "downloaded.txt"; // local file to save text in
string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename); // local path to save file to
File.WriteAllText(localPath, text); // writes to local storage
myTextView.Text = text; // updates the TextView element on the screen with downloaded text data
```

Then Just

```
var url = new Uri("https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude +"&key=YOUR KEY HERE");
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

Im just not sure of the encoding method for JSON.
If anyone knows please answer thanks...

Comment: I would recommend to use HttpClient or ModernHttpClient. Both have a simpler api and are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WebClient` class in `System.Net`:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
```

Origin answer:
[How to get a json string from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url)

Comment: I can post the system log but [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66vfwSXdArkRzVRTWZqTnVSTHc/view?usp=sharing) @Raskayu

Comment: Try like this: `var url = new Uri(url link);
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
                }`  and for parse the json string result to get an actual object see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-the-simplest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object) @LachlanJones PD: I've tried the solution and I can get a correct json string answer, just saying that my location was wrong :P